# Scala + JDBC = Driver not found after compilation

Tags: java, scala, jdbc, playframework-2.0

I am using **Scala, Play, JDBC** to create a **DB connection** on the fly in a web app (secondary connection besides the default one).

Everything works fine, I load the driver with **Class.forName**, but there is a small and strange issue - when **recompiling** a scala file which contains the connection related code, exception gets thrown on the next requests from web, that driver file can’t be found. Play server restart cures this and everything works fine till the next time the Scala file is edited & compiled.

It only happens when editing and compiling the file, when app is just running the connections work fine. This is not a major issue, just strange behaviour.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble with sqlite and here was my solution

```
try {
  DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.sqlite.JDBC)
} catch {
  case e: Exception => //Log your error
}
```

I got the idea from [This bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48214)

Has something to do with when play shuts down for recompiling it un registers the jdbc drivers, but the mechanism for auto loading drivers happens in the java start up not the app start up. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use scalikeJDBC which is a scala like JDBC CONNECTION LIBRARY  http://scalikeJDBC.org the documentation is good

Comment: Actually I am already using ScalikeJDBC, but the problem is just related to JDBC and driver loading. No abstraction is going to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

in scala no need to load the driver like this

```
Class.forName("Driver")
```

This is java code,in eclipse scala ide just open **conf/application.conf** file and set the default driver...
like this

```
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default1.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly in this case I can't use **application.conf**, because the connection must be created on the fly. The connection settings are not known until that exact moment. I removed **Class.forName**, and it actually makes no difference, because, as you said, it is not needed.